# ssh-keygen without ssh access

Tags: shell, ssh, scp

I've got a Lacie Network Space 2 where they have disabled the SSH access and I'd like to write a script where I transfer files from my computer to the NS2 using scp.
The only problem I have is that I can't (from what I know) generate a public key without first connecting via SSH.

So my question is: Is it possible to generate a key without having access to SSH, for use with scp? Or some other clever way to transfer files to my NS2 (FW 2.2.4) using a script.

I might add that I'm currently mounting the disk and using cp, but I'd like something better.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that if you want to gain access to ssh keys on your NS2 with a newer FW you have to remove the disk from its casing and connect it to a computer, as they explain in this link
[Enabling SSH on NS2](http://lacie.nas-central.org/wiki/Enabling_ssh_with_disassembling_%28Network_space_2%29)

I thank you both for your answers, but I guess I'll have to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want? If you want to scp to the NS2, you'll have to generate the keys on the source machines and append it to authorized_keys on the target. Since you can already mount & use cp, you should be able to do that.

Note that since `scp` works over `ssh`, if they've disabled ssh this won't work. OTOH, if they've only disabled password based ssh, or set /bin/false as your shell, this might work.

Comment: The thing is that I can manually use scp/sftp but I can't ssh to the NS2. The only thing I really want to know is if I can generate a key without connecting via ssh

Comment: Yes you can. Generate it on another machine.

Comment: How do you mean? I'm betting I can't generate a key to another server and then use that same key to logon to my NS2?

Comment: Generate the keys on another machine, append the public key to authorized_keys on NS2.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand what you mean. But I can't get to "authorized keys". When I'm "mounting" it I'm using Transmit to "fool" my computer to believe that the sftp connection is a local volume. Which means that I can't see the files/directories above the ftp-directory

Comment: If you dont have any keys on that server yet, can you just manually sftp in and push ~/.ssh/authorized_keys? (else pull it, append locally, then push the modified one)

Comment: I tried creating the .ssh directory in / on the server, but as it turns out I'm not allowed to create files there, only in the three subfolders that were there from the beginning. Nice idea though, thanks